# Dynamodb - automatically updating GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When you update an item on a table, will all items be reflected on the index, including its primary key(s) and projections? The docs mention that it does, but it wasn't specific enough.

Also, the image below shows an example of a composite key made up of `Status` and `Date` fields in the table. It was specifically to show how modeling can drastically improve performance. However, I couldn't help but wonder: Does `StatusDate` update itself when `Status` changes? How does this work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you update an item, all projections and indexes are updated as well.

However, both [Local Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) and [Global Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) behave in an eventually consistent fashion. This means you can end up reading data that is stale.

Fortunately, at least on Local Secondary Indexes, you can request a [strongly consistent read](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html).

Now, about `StatusDate` and composite indexes, this is done on the application level.